# How can i get user information from Latest Facebook sdk-4.0.1

Tags: android, facebook

How can i get user information from Latest Facebook sdk-4.0.1 ,, like :

email - user_birthday - user_friends

Notice : I use LoginButton

```
    final LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_birthday");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the permissions can be setup in one line:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends, public_profile, email, user_birthday"));
```

Now, considering you registered a callback in this way:

```
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) { }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() { }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) { }
    });
```

Place this code in the onSuccess() method:

```
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest( loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted( JSONObject object,  GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.d("onCompleted",object.toString());
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link, email");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
```

Pay attention in this line:

```
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link, email");
```

...these will be the fields returned in the JSONObject in the `onCompleted()` method.

Reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#reading
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user